# How to insert a blank space(&nbsp) into a Beautifulsoup tag?

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to add a '&nbsp' into a Beautifulsoup tag.  BS converts the `tag.string` to `\&ampamp;nbsp;` instead of `&nbsp`.  It has to be some encoding issue but I can't figure it out.

PLEASE NOTE: ignore the back '\' character.  I had to add it so stackoverflow would format my question correctly.

```
import bs4 as Beautifulsoup

html = "<td><span></span></td>"
soup = Beautifulsoup(html)
tag = soup.find("td")
tag.string = "&nbsp;"
```

Current output is html = "\&amp;nbsp;"

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you printing the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `BeautifulSoup` uses `minimal` output formatter and converts HTML entities.

The solution is to set output formatter to `None`, quote from BS source (`PageElement` docstring):

```
# There are five possible values for the "formatter" argument passed in
# to methods like encode() and prettify():
#
# "html" - All Unicode characters with corresponding HTML entities
#   are converted to those entities on output.
# "minimal" - Bare ampersands and angle brackets are converted to
#   XML entities: &amp; &lt; &gt;
# None - The null formatter. Unicode characters are never
#   converted to entities.  This is not recommended, but it's
#   faster than "minimal".
```

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = "<td><span></span></td>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
tag = soup.find("span")
tag.string = '&nbsp;'

print soup.prettify(formatter=None)
```

prints:

```
<td>
 <span>
  &nbsp;
 </span>
</td>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect!  I just found the answer also.  Thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 4):

Although [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22187269/250962) by alecxe works if you don't mind using `formatter=None`, that's not useful if you want to insert an `&nbsp;` into some HTML that you *do* want to have a specific formatting (like `"html5"` or `"html"`).

I've found that Muposat's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38926630/250962) of using `"\xa0"` does the trick for me.

So, to adapt alecxe's answer:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<td><span></span></td>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
tag = soup.find("span")
tag.string = "\xa0"

print soup.prettify(formatter="html5")
```

prints:

```html
<td>
 <span>
  &nbsp;
 </span>
</td>
```

This is using python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add unicode non-breaking space, which can be represented as "\xa0" in python:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("", "html5lib") # html5lib will add html and body tags by default
soup.body.string = "\xa0" # uncode non-breaking space
soup.encode("ascii") # to see final html in ascii encoding
```

Result:

```
b'<html><head></head><body>&#160;</body></html>'
```